# How to retrieve the ID of an object in .NET MVC project

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

Say I have a Reaction class with an associated View. Each reaction should be posted in a specific ModuleSession. So the ModuleSession class contains a collection of reactions. What is the most convenient way to obtain the Id of the current ModuleSession when a new Reaction is created?

Comment: what is a asp mvc _Reaction_?

Comment: @gerdi - http://reactjs.net/ ?